# How to hide markers and set background color of react-apexchart's are chart?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps-markers, apexcharts, react-apexcharts

[image]

This image shows my current result. Coming data structure is below:

```
const data = [
 {
  "value": 32.667,
  "timestamp": "2023-12-21T22:20:00",
  "isPreviousReading": true
 },
 {
  "value": 32.133,
  "timestamp": "2023-12-21T22:25:00",
  "isPreviousReading": false
 },
 {
  "value": 32.133,
  "timestamp": "2023-12-21T22:30:00",
  "isPreviousReading": true
 },
 {
  "value": 32.133,
  "timestamp": "2023-12-21T22:35:00",
  "isPreviousReading": true
 },
 {
  "value": 32.133,
  "timestamp": "2023-12-21T22:40:00",
  "isPreviousReading": true
 },
]
```

According to the data, when isPreviousReading is true, I need to hide marker from my chart. And I need to change the background color of that point. Is it possible? If it is possible can you help me to solve this issue? You can check my code below:

```
import React from "react";
import Chart from "react-apexcharts";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";
import { format } from "date-fns";
import Skeleton from "@mui/material/Skeleton";

import { useAppDispatch, useAppSelector } from "../../stores/hooks";
import { GetGraphData } from "../../stores/wellSlice";
import Cookies from "js-cookie";

const dateTypes = {
  FIVE_MINUTELY: 120,
  FIFTEEN_MINUTELY: 120,
  HOURLY: 120,
  DAILY: 30,
  MONTHLY: 12,
  YEARLY: 3,
};

function HookFiveMinutely(props: any) {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(null);
  const [category, setCategory] = React.useState([]);
  const [minPressValue, setMinPressValue] = React.useState(0);
  const [maxPressValue, setMaxPressValue] = React.useState(0);
  const { well, auth } = useAppSelector((state) => state);
  const params = useParams();
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const currentLang = Cookies.get("i18next");

  const translations = {
    exportToSVG: t("download_SVG"),
    exportToPNG: t("download_PNG"),
    exportToCSV: t("download_CSV"),
  };

  const getAllGraphData = React.useCallback(() => {
    if (params.id && auth.token) {
      dispatch(
        GetGraphData({
          data: {
            dateTime: well.dateTime,
            page: 0,
            size: dateTypes[props.type],
            stationId: params?.id,
            type: props.type,
          },
          token: auth.token,
          callback(payload) {
            let presUp = payload?.sensors
              ?.find(
                (item: any) =>
                  item?.type == "PRESSURE" && item?.direction == "UPLINK"
              )
              ?.sensorReadings?.map((item: any) => item?.value);
            let presDwn = payload?.sensors
              ?.find(
                (item: any) =>
                  item?.type == "PRESSURE" && item?.direction == "DOWNLINK"
              )
              ?.sensorReadings?.map((item: any) => item?.value);

            let temperature = payload?.sensors
              ?.find((item: any) => item.unit == "CELSIUS")
              ?.sensorReadings?.map((item: any) => item.value);
            let category = payload?.sensors
              ?.find((item: any) => item.unit == "KGF_CM2")
              ?.sensorReadings?.map((item: any) => {
                return item.timestamp;
              });
            setMinPressValue(payload.minLimitForPressure);
            setMaxPressValue(payload.maxLimitForPressure);

            const newData = [
              {
                data: { val: presUp, type: "presUp" },
              },
              {
                data: { val: presDwn, type: "presDwn" },
              },
              {
                data: { val: temperature, type: "temp" },
              },
            ];

            const modified = newData.filter(
              (item) => item.data.val !== undefined
            );

            setData(modified);
            setCategory(category);
          },
        })
      );
    }
  }, [well?.dateTime, params.id, dispatch, auth.token, currentLang]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    getAllGraphData();
  }, [getAllGraphData]);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {!well.graphIsloading && data ? (
        <Chart
          type="area"
          series={[
            {
              name: t("pres1"),
              color: "#f98b2d",
              data:
                data.find((item) => {
                  if (item.data.type == "presUp") return item.data.val;
                })?.data?.val || [],
              type: "area",
              fill: {
                type: "gradient",
                gradient: {
                  shadeIntensity: 1,
                  opacityFrom: 0.7,
                  opacityTo: 1,
                  stops: [0, 90, 100],
                },
              },
            },
            {
              name: t("pres2"),
              data:
                data.find((item) => {
                  if (item.data.type == "presDwn") return item.data.val;
                })?.data?.val || [],
              color: "#1c3faa",
              type: "area",
              fill: {
                type: "gradient",
                gradient: {
                  shadeIntensity: 1,
                  opacityFrom: 0.7,
                  opacityTo: 1,
                  stops: [0, 90, 100],
                },
              },
            },
            {
              name: t("temperature"),
              color: "#d87183",
              type: "column",
              data:
                data.find((item) => {
                  if (item.data.type == "temp") return item.data.val;
                })?.data?.val || [],
            },
          ].filter((item) => item.data.length)}
          options={{
            chart: {
              marginLeft: "10px",
              marginRight: "10px",
              animations: {
                enabled: true,
                easing: "ease",
                speed: 800,
                animateGradually: {
                  enabled: true,
                  delay: 150,
                },
                dynamicAnimation: {
                  enabled: true,
                  speed: 350,
                },
              },
              fontFamily: "Roboto, sans-serif",
              zoom: {
                autoScaleYaxis: true,
                enabed: true,
                type: "x",
              },
              height: "400px",
              type: "area",
              id: "ctxinternalchart",
              toolbar: {
                show: true,
              },
              locales: [
                {
                  name: "en",
                  options: {
                    toolbar: {
                      exportToSVG: "Download SVG",
                      exportToPNG: "Download PNG",
                      exportToCSV: "Download CSV",
                    },
                  },
                },
                {
                  name: "uz",
                  options: {
                    toolbar: {
                      exportToSVG: "SVGni yuklash",
                      exportToPNG: "PNGni yuklash",
                      exportToCSV: "CSVni yuklash",
                    },
                  },
                },
                {
                  name: "ru",
                  options: {
                    toolbar: {
                      exportToSVG: "Скачать SVG",
                      exportToPNG: "Скачать PNG",
                      exportToCSV: "Скачать CSV",
                    },
                  },
                },
              ],
              defaultLocale: currentLang,
            },
            markers: {
              size: 5,
              hover: {
                size: 7,
              },
            },
            menu: {
              contextMenu: Object.keys(translations).map((key) => ({
                text: translations[key],
              })),
            },
            title: {
              text: undefined,
              align: "left",
              offsetX: -6,
            },
            dataLabels: {
              enabled: false,
            },
            grid: {
              padding: {
                right: 5,
                left: 5,
              },
            },
            stroke: {
              show: true,
              curve: "smooth",
              lineCap: "butt",
              colors: undefined,
              width: 1.5,
              dashArray: 0,
            },
            xaxis: {
              categories: category,
              type: "category",
              crosshairs: {
                show: true,
                width: 1,
                position: "front",
                opacity: 1,
                dropShadow: {
                  enabled: false,
                  top: 0,
                  left: 0,
                  blur: 1,
                  opacity: 0.4,
                },
              },
              labels: {
                formatter: (
                  value: string,
                  timestamp?: number | undefined,
                  opts?: any
                ) => props.formatter(value, timestamp, opts),
              },
              tickAmount: 20,
              tickPlacement: "on",
              tooltip: {
                enabled: false,
              },
            },
            tooltip: {
              x: {
                show: true,
                formatter(value, _) {
                  return format(
                    new Date(category[value - 1]),
                    "HH:mm dd.MM.yyyy"
                  );
                },
              },
            },
            yaxis: [
              {
                seriesName: "presUp",
                min: minPressValue,
                max: maxPressValue,
                values:
                  data.find((item: any) => {
                    if (item.data.type == "presUp") return item.data.val;
                  })?.data?.val || [],
              },
              {
                seriesName: "presDwn",
                show: false,
                min: minPressValue,
                max: maxPressValue,
                values:
                  data.find((item: any) => {
                    if (item.data.type == "presDwn") return item.data.val;
                  })?.data?.val || [],
              },
              {
                seriesName: "temp",
                opposite: true,
                values:
                  data.find((item: any) => {
                    if (item.data.type == "temp") return item.data.val;
                  })?.data?.val || [],
                show: true,
                max: 300,
                axisTicks: {
                  show: false,
                },
                axisBorder: {
                  show: false,
                  color: "#247BA0",
                },
                labels: {
                  style: {
                    colors: "#D0869B",
                  },
                },
              },
            ]
              .filter((item) => item.values.length)
              .map((item) => {
                let prsUpData =
                  data.find((prs: any) => {
                    if (prs.data.type == "presUp") return prs.data.val;
                  })?.data?.val || [];
                if (
                  !prsUpData.length &&
                  (item.seriesName == "presDwn" || item.seriesName == "temp")
                ) {
                  return {
                    ...item,
                    show: true,
                  };
                } else {
                  return item;
                }
              }),
          }}
          height="340%"
        />
      ) : (
        <Skeleton className="col-span-8" variant="rounded" height="400px" />
      )}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default React.memo(HookFiveMinutely);
```

I want a result like this.

[image]

As an image, there is not markers when isPreviousReading is true and background is changed as well. To achieve this solution, what i need to do?

If you know the answer, please let me know it as well.